# Summing over y values for same x value

Tags: gnuplot

I want gnuplot to plot the sum of all z values in all cases where the x and y values are equal.

A dummy data file looks like this:

```
#testfile
0 0 1
0 1 1
0 1 1
0 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 1 2
```

I am using `plot "testfile" u 1:2:3 w p ps variable` to scale the points according to the value in the third column, and I would like to find a command that gives the same plot for the above data file as if I were to plot this data file:

```
#testfile2
0 0 1
0 1 3
1 0 1
1 1 5
```

If that makes it easier, in my real data file, I always have to sum over two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you're looking for a `gnuplot`-only solution, but what you want could be accomplished with a simple `awk` one-liner, either ran separate or embedded on `gnuplot`. By the way, this assumes that you you *always* have to sum over two lines:

Input file:

```
0 1 1
0 1 1
1 0 1
1 0 2
1 1 2
1 1 2
```

By running:

```
awk '{sum+=$3} (NR%2)==0{print $1,$2,sum; sum=0;}' testfile
```

You would get:

```
0 1 2
1 0 3
1 1 4
```

Then you could save in a separate file and plot with the line you mentioned above. Alternatively, you can embed the `awk` line within `gnuplot` using:

```
plot "<awk '{sum+=$3} (NR%2)==0{print $1,$2,sum; sum=0;}' testfile" u 1:2:3 not w p ps variable pt 7
```

Hope it helps!